# Error due to Order of Code on Application relating to NFC

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, nfc, text-to-speech, translate

Disclaimer: I am extremely new to Android Studio

I am currently developing an app where when an NFC tag is scanned that contains plain text, it will read loud the text. It is also capable of writing text on the NFC tag. However, I wanted to implement a translation button that translates the scanned text using Google API service.

However, when I implement the translation code, I get a collection of errors in the Translate Button area. These includes "Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'", "Annotations are not allowed here" for @overdrive, and "Cannot resolve symbol 'v'"

The reason I am making this into one question is because I assume it is an error relating to the order of the code. I have tried to research this problem in which people say to put it in the onCreate() section but I tried that and had no luck.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
{
    public static final String Error_Detected = "No NFC Tag Detected";
    public static final String Write_Success = "Text Written Successfully!";
    public static final String Write_Error = "Error during Writing, Try Again!";
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writingTagFilters[];
    boolean writeMode;
    Tag myTag;
    Context context;
    TextView edit_message;
    TextView nfc_contents;
    Button ActivateButton;
    TextToSpeech mTTS;
    private String originalText;
    private String translatedText;
    private boolean connected;
    private TextView translatedTv;
    Translate translate;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    nfc_contents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nfc_contents);
    ActivateButton = findViewById(R.id.ActivateButton);
    context = this;


    ActivateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(myTag ==null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, Error_Detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    write("PlainText|"+edit_message.getText().toString(), myTag);
                    Toast.makeText(context, Write_Success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Write_Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Write_Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    mTTS = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            String toSpeak = edit_message.getText().toString().trim();
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                //if there is no error then set language
                mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //speak the text
                mTTS.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        }
    });
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if(nfcAdapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    readFromIntent(getIntent());
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    writingTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };
}
private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage [rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }
        buildTagViews(msgs);
    }
}
private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
    if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

    String text ="";

    byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
    String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
    int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;

    try {
        text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
    }

    nfc_contents.setText("NFC Content: " + text);
    mTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {
    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
    NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);

    ndef.connect();

    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);

    ndef.close();
}
private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String lang        ="en";
    byte[] textBytes   =text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes   =lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int    langLength  =langBytes.length;
    int    textLength  =textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload     =new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;


    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1, langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1+langLength,textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload);

    return recordNFC;
}


Button translateButton = findViewById(R.id.translateButton);

    translateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (checkInternetConnection()) {

            //If there is internet connection, get translate service and start translation:
            getTranslateService();
            translate();

        } else {

            //If not, display "no connection" warning:
            translatedTv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_connection));
        }

    }
};

public void getTranslateService() {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try (InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.seeapp)) {

        //Get credentials:
        final GoogleCredentials myCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(is);

        //Set credentials and get translate service:
        TranslateOptions translateOptions = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(myCredentials).build();
        translate = translateOptions.getService();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }
}

public void translate() {

    //Get input text to be translated:
    originalText = edit_message.getText().toString();
    Translation translation = translate.translate(originalText, Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("tr"), Translate.TranslateOption.model("base"));
    translatedText = translation.getTranslatedText();

    //Translated text and original text are set to TextViews:
    translatedTv.setText(translatedText);

}

public boolean checkInternetConnection() {

    //Check internet connection:
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    //Means that we are connected to a network (mobile or wi-fi)
    connected = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;

    return connected;
}
```

Comment: if you're having problems understanding/resolving `"Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'"` and `"Cannot resolve symbol 'v'"` perhaps you should consider learning some basics before attempting this

Comment: Using NFC is not really a topic for a new developer, especially writing to NFC as there are so many case you need to handle and be aware of to make a successful App. And Google's and other people examples are using the old poor API and don't really cover everything needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button translateButton = findViewById(R.id.translateButton);
...
```

Is outside any class method, and therefore if memory serve me correct will be run on class construction which is wrong.

The whole code example you gave reformat to what should be correct.

```
{
    public static final String Error_Detected = "No NFC Tag Detected";
    public static final String Write_Success = "Text Written Successfully!";
    public static final String Write_Error = "Error during Writing, Try Again!";
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writingTagFilters[];
    boolean writeMode;
    Tag myTag;
    Context context;
    TextView edit_message;
    TextView nfc_contents;
    Button ActivateButton;
    TextToSpeech mTTS;
    private String originalText;
    private String translatedText;
    private boolean connected;
    private TextView translatedTv;
    Translate translate;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    nfc_contents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nfc_contents);
    ActivateButton = findViewById(R.id.ActivateButton);
    context = this;


    ActivateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(myTag ==null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, Error_Detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    write("PlainText|"+edit_message.getText().toString(), myTag);
                    Toast.makeText(context, Write_Success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Write_Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Write_Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Code inserted in onCreate
    Button translateButton = findViewById(R.id.translateButton);

    translateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          if (checkInternetConnection()) {

            //If there is internet connection, get translate service and start translation:
            getTranslateService();
            translate();

          } else {

            //If not, display "no connection" warning:
            translatedTv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_connection));
          }
      }
    };


    mTTS = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            String toSpeak = edit_message.getText().toString().trim();
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                //if there is no error then set language
                mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //speak the text
                mTTS.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        }
    });
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if(nfcAdapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    readFromIntent(getIntent());
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    writingTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };
}
private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage [rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }
        buildTagViews(msgs);
    }
}
private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
    if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

    String text ="";

    byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
    String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
    int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;

    try {
        text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
    }

    nfc_contents.setText("NFC Content: " + text);
    mTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {
    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
    NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);

    ndef.connect();

    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);

    ndef.close();
}
private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String lang        ="en";
    byte[] textBytes   =text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes   =lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int    langLength  =langBytes.length;
    int    textLength  =textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload     =new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;


    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1, langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1+langLength,textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload);

    return recordNFC;
}

public void getTranslateService() {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try (InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.seeapp)) {

        //Get credentials:
        final GoogleCredentials myCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(is);

        //Set credentials and get translate service:
        TranslateOptions translateOptions = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(myCredentials).build();
        translate = translateOptions.getService();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }
}

public void translate() {

    //Get input text to be translated:
    originalText = edit_message.getText().toString();
    Translation translation = translate.translate(originalText, Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("tr"), Translate.TranslateOption.model("base"));
    translatedText = translation.getTranslatedText();

    //Translated text and original text are set to TextViews:
    translatedTv.setText(translatedText);

}

public boolean checkInternetConnection() {

    //Check internet connection:
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    //Means that we are connected to a network (mobile or wi-fi)
    connected = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;

    return connected;
}
```